# Condition in having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, having

I have a question:
Can I put a condition in having clause ?

I have tried a condition like this:

```
 SELECT  distinct
 U.ID as USERID,        
 U.CODE_PAYS,
 T.SKU,
 T.URL_IMAGE,
 T.PRODUCT_NAME_WEBSITE,
 T.BASELINE_1,
 T.URL_FICHE_PRODUIT  
 FROM DATA_CATALOGUE_MARKETING T 
 INNER JOIN USERS_CONTACT U
 ON T.CODE_PAYS = U.CODE_PAYS
 INNER JOIN DATA_TRANSACTION_DETAILS DTD ON DTD.ID_CONTACT = U.ID AND DTD.CODE_PAYS = U.CODE_PAYS
 INNER JOIN DATA_CATALOGUE_MARKETING DCM ON DCM.SKU = DTD.SKU   AND T.INTERNAL_REF = DCM.INTERNAL_REF_NON_SAMPLE
 AND DCM.CODE_PAYS = DTD.CODE_PAYS
 AND DCM.GROUPE_ATTRIBUT = 'Sample'
 GROUP BY  U.ID, U.CODE_PAYS, T.SKU, T.URL_IMAGE_PRODUIT, T.PRODUCT_NAME_WEBSITE, T.BASELINE_1, T.URL_FICHE_PRODUIT 
 AND 
 (
    (
        U.CODE_PAYS = 'GB'
        HAVING MAX(convert(date,TRANS_DATE,120))) = convert(date,GETDATE()-14,120)
    )
    OR
    (
        U.CODE_PAYS = 'FR'
        HAVING MAX(convert(date,TRANS_DATE,120))) = convert(date,GETDATE()-24,120)
    )
 )
```

This condition doesn't work. How can I make a condition to patch this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: please show us your full query! `Having`  is used after `group by` which is not clear in what you have shown

Comment: Can you post the full query for better understanding. Now it looks like it is part of `Where` clause but Having cannot be used in Where clause

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CASE WHEN:

```
HAVING MAX(convert(date,TRANS_DATE,120)) = (CASE WHEN U.CODE_PAYS = 'GB' THEN convert(date,GETDATE()-14,120)
                                                 WHEN U.CODE_PAYS = 'FR' THEN convert(date,GETDATE()-24,120)
                                                 ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition in having clause but not put having clause in a condition

HAVING is clause for filter group by result not a function ..eg

```
 ........

 GROUP BY  U.ID, U.CODE_PAYS, T.SKU, T.URL_IMAGE_PRODUIT, T.PRODUCT_NAME_WEBSITE, T.BASELINE_1, T.URL_FICHE_PRODUIT
 HAVING MAX(convert(date,TRANS_DATE,120))) = convert(date,GETDATE()-14,120)
.......
```

Comment: Ok I understand, I have make this example to understand what I need.
How can I put a condition in having clause ?